# How to wait for a result from AsyncTask from a main thread?

Tags: android, web-services, android-asynctask, policy

Is there a method I could use in my Main thread, to wait for the result from an AsyncTask (in my case a value from a web-service) ?

I made a workaround without using AsyncTask  but I know it's not the correct way:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 
    }
```

Could you help with hints in order to use an AsyncTask?
Thanks.

Comment: If any of the given answers helped solve your problem, please check the checkmark beside that answer :) If none of the answers helped and you need further assistance, please edit your question to provide more information.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `onPostExecute()` method.
When all the work in the background is finished, onPostExecute() which is in on your main thread will be called.

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        //Do your stuffs here on Main UI thread.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the onPostExecute of your asynctask to call the method of your main thread, or just do whatever you need doing.

```
private class AsyncCaller extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //this method will be running on UI thread

    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        //this method will be running on UI thread
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`onPostExecute()` method of `AsyncTask` runs in the main thread. You can rely on it to wait for a result from AsyncTask from a main thread.

```
private class AsyncWait extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //Whatever is done here, will run on main thread
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //Whatever is done here, will run on background thread
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //Whatever is done here, will run on main thread
    }
}
```

From the main thread:

```
new AsyncWait().execute();
```